# Проблема с регистрацией в unity

Tags: unity3d

Я установил unity(3.1.2), и при входе просят зарегистрироваться, нажимаю на ссылку и сайт не загружается(с интернетом порядок)[image: скриншот сайта]

Comment: А если через впн?))

Comment: Возможно из России временно нельзя зарегистрироваться в Unity

Comment: A как тогда без регистрации?